# Visual studio add in context menu does not receive events

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I'm experimenting with a visual studio addon and have come across very odd behaviour. I'm adding a right click context menu item and I'm not getting the events to fire *unless* I put a breakpoint in the `OnConnect` method and wait a little while. I'm doing pretty much exactly as in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12244/Adding-Menu-Items-to-context-menus-inside-the-Visu).

It's a totally standard add-in with this code:

```
public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
{
    applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
    addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;

    var commandBars = ((CommandBars)applicationObject.CommandBars)["Code Window"];
    var popup = commandBars.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 1, true);
    popup.Caption = "View graph";
    var commandBarEvents = (CommandBarEvents)(applicationObject.Events.CommandBarEvents[popup]);
    commandBarEvents.Click += ViewGraphClick;
}

private void ViewGraphClick(object commandbarcontrol, ref bool handled, ref bool canceldefault)
{
    var selection = (TextSelection)applicationObject.ActiveDocument.Selection;
    selection.Insert("Hello, world!");
    handled = true;
}
```

If I wait with a breakpoint early in the method, this addon will work. If I don't wait it will never call my event. It will however add my item to the context menu in all cases.

As far as I can see this method only gets called once. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

**Update:** I've tried to put the same initialization code in `OnStartup`. The result is the same. I've also tried to do as per the example shown [here](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2004/MZ2004003.aspx), but my `OnConnection` only gets called once with the `connectMode` set to `Startup`.

**Update 2** I've tried as many combinations of this as possible, moving all the initialization around. Eventually, I gave up and started using another example which uses commands instead of plain context menus. This is probably a better solution in the long run, but I'm still interested in why the original code didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make these variables global:

```
    CommandBarEvents commandBarEvents;
    CommandBar commandBars;
    CommandBarControl popup;
```

If you create these objects in OnConnection, they are disposed as soon as the code goes out of scope.